# How can I get an empty link "clicked" programmatically in React.js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-navigation

I am not sure if this is exactly what I need, so I'll explain my situation
I am using CSS to show a popup window by using the `:target` state to set the visibility and opacity of it correctly.
On the popup I have an X that sets a new empty target when clicked, this closes the popup as it is not the target anymore.
This is my X link:

```
  <a href="#" className="project-form__close">
    ✖
  </a>
```

My problem is this - the popup is actually a form, and I'd like it to close automatically when the form submits, without the user actually having to click anything.
How can I do that? I'm not actually navigating anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices:

1. Call the `.click()` method on the link, to simulate a click
2. Just do `window.location.hash = '';` to perform the same effect directly